# Exception: trim epects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Hello i recently tried to implement **JWT** authentication in my app by following this tutorial i found online:

[cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

However when trying to install the following package:

> barryvdh/laravel-cors 0.4.x@dev

I got an error exception when trying to run **php artisan clear-compiled**
and later when i tried to run **php artisan vendor:publish**

This is the error:

```
[ErrorException]
trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Edit: I just removed the package and tried running **composer update**, had the same error again.

Answer (score 4):

Okay i found the error, it had to do with my routes file:

```
Route::any(['{url?}'], function($url) {
    return view('website/index');
})->where(['url' => '[-a-zA-Z0-9/]+']);
```

I removed the square brackets and now it works, must have accidentally put it there:

```
Route::any('{url?}', function($url) {
    return view('website/index');
})->where(['url' => '[-a-zA-Z0-9/]+']);
```

Not gonna delete though, somebody might find this useful lol xD xD

Comment: There is a closing reason for that kind of problems that are triggered by accidential typos. You may just delete your question, or get it closed (and then deleted, if it gained no upvotes).

Comment: @Sven no need to delete it. SO has millions of storage. In fact I was also the victim of those brackets and this answer got over 1.8k views